# ArcGIS Server - Polygon lines dimenstions

Tags: arcgis-server, vb.net, arcgis-web-adf

How to measure the lines of polygon . VB.NET + ArcGIS Server .

I have ArcGIS Server 9.3 - WebADF - VB.NET

Comment: Please explain your question & software platform (like ArcGIS Server 10.0 Web ADF etc ) in detail..

Comment: may be useful http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=158&f=2276&t=259198

Comment: I want to know the measures line by line , not the total outbound measure . thanx